# How to load Appcomponent class before routing takes place

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-components, angular2-guards

I have set routing and display the page according to user roles. For this i am using guard on route. I am extracting userRole from service in Appcomponent class and using set and get method in main-service file. Now problem is that before i get role, routing takes place and it navigate to wrong url as it doesn't have role by then. Tough from next call, it works properly. Let me share the code:-
1.Here is guard class:-

```
export class HomeGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _router: Router,private mainService: MainService) {
    }
    canActivate(): boolean {
        let userRoles:any;
        alert('HomeGuard');
        userRoles = this.mainService.getSavedUserRole();
        //userRoles = ['Profile Manager','Operations','Shipper'];
        alert('userRoles are here'+userRoles);
        console.log('here in homeguard');
        if(userRoles) {
            if(userRoles.some(x => x === 'Shipper') || userRoles.some(x => x === 'Admin'))
                return true;
        }
        this._router.navigate(['/notfound']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

2. Here is AppComponent where i am extracting userRole from service:-

   ```
   export class AppComponent {
     savedUserRoles:any;
     constructor(private translate: TranslateService,private mainService: MainService) {
         console.log('Environment config', Config);
         // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
         translate.setDefaultLang(AppSettings.LNG_TYPE);
         // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
         translate.use(AppSettings.LNG_TYPE);
         this.mainService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(result => {
           this.savedUserRoles = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result._body).Data).Roles;
           console.log('sdfghj'+this.savedUserRoles);
           this.mainService.setSavedUserRole(this.savedUserRoles);
         });
     }
   }
   ```
3. Here is main-service where i have defined set and get method:-

   setSavedUserRole(name: any) {
       console.log('main'+name);
       this._userRoles = name;
       }

   ```
   getSavedUserRole() {
       return this._userRoles;
   }
   ```

Comment: you need to put the fetching of your roles in a `resolver`. The `resolver` will run before the appcomponent is loaded and your `guard` can use the `resolver` to check `canActivate()`

Comment: Can you please give me sample code for this?

Comment: I thought the `resolver` runs before the `canActivate` but after looking into it I was wrong.  Another option you have is when the user authentications, pull in the user details / roles after successful authentication and store those details in the `localStorage`.  Then in your `CanActivate` you can pull the user roles for the current authenticated user from the `localStorage`